# Book on the rise of digital photography

Tags: books, history, technology-generations

I am very interested in recent developments in photography. Over the last 10-15 years there have been major upheavals in the industry, including the complete switch to digital and the death of photo giants like Polariod and (nearly) Kodak.

Does there exist a comprehensive book detailing these events and what mistakes were made by those who died, and the right things done by those who lived?

Comment: Great question! Would love to get some info on this too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've taken a look around and I don't see anything specifically on the rise of Digital Photography, though the topic is lightly covered in various books. This seems to be the best I could find:

[http://www.amazon.com/Camera-History-Photography-Daguerreotype-Digital/dp/1454900024/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1333057960&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1454900024)

There is also a short article on luminous landscapes on the topic, but it's mostly an opinion piece:

http://www.luminous-landscape.com/essays/rise-fall.shtml

The story is still being told, so there doesn't seem to be a comprehensive accounting of the history just yet. Great question though.